# How to change the searched text under the cursor in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim

Let say that you have the following text:

```
test_text
test_text_1
test_text_2
```

and you search for "text" (`/text`) and your cursor will go on the third "t" from "test_text", then how to change it (the "text")?

How to change the current highlighted region (a.k.a. the "text" where my cursor is in)?

ci **current_highlighted_region**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent Vim versions (7.4 and later patch levels of 7.3), you have a `gn` command that operates on the current / next search match. So `cgn` will edit the current match.